# EncoderDecoder model training/prediction with two different tokenizers

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, encoder-decoder

I am currently trying to get a hang of the EncoderDecoder model for seq2seq task from pretrained decoder models.
I am a bit confused about how to create a Encoder-decoder from two pretrained Bert models with different tokenizers and different vocabs. I am currently trying to build a seq2seq English to German encoder-decoder model with bert-uncased and dbmdz / bert-base-german-uncased. I know that there are models which have a tokenizer with shared vocab, but I for my future project I specifically want to work with two models that do not have that.

I was able to create a model and start training by adding cls-, sep- and pad-token of the decoder tokenizer to the EncoderDecoder config as start-,eos- and pad-token respectively (as was described in the colab : Google Colab).

During training the loss decreases to nearly 0 during the first epoch (when using a training set of 100k entires), while the validation loss stays high (~25).
When I use the model to generate a translation, I get several start tokens followed by repetition of random tokens (though they seem to me to be topical related, i.e the german words for "Britain", "British", "France", "French", "German" or "ours", "yours", "mine" etc.).
The output is nearly identical for any input, though some prompts lead to slight variations, however it seems basically just the associations between words the pretrained model has learned.

The fact that training loss is around 0 at the start of training suggests to me that I made an error either with setting up the labels, or setting up the model config.

Below is the code I used for creating, training and generation.

If anybody has an idea what could

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
import numpy as np
from transformers import EncoderDecoderModel 
import torch
import datasets
from transformers import Seq2SeqTrainingArguments, Seq2SeqTrainer

#loading model and tokenizer
model = EncoderDecoderModel.from_encoder_decoder_pretrained("bert-base-uncased","dbmdz/bert-base-german-uncased")

tokenizer_ger = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("dbmdz/bert-base-german-uncased")
tokenizer_en = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

model.config.decoder_start_token_id = tokenizer_ger.cls_token_id
model.config.eos_token_id = tokenizer_ger.sep_token_id
model.config.pad_token_id = tokenizer_ger.pad_token_id


model.config.max_length = 102
model.config.min_length = 12
model.config.no_repeat_ngram_size = 3
model.config.early_stopping = True

#shorter sequences seem to be fitting, since most of the input is less than 100 tokens
model.config.length_penalty = -1.0
model.config.num_beams = 3

#perparing dataset

train = datasets.load_dataset("wmt14","de-en")
train_dataset = pd.DataFrame([x["translation"] for x in train["train"]])
test_dataset = pd.DataFrame([x["translation"] for x in train["test"]])


#smaller subset for training /troubleshooting

train_dataset = train_dataset.sample(1000)

train_dataset["e_length"] = [len(tokenizer_en(x).input_ids) for x in train_dataset["en"]]

train_dataset["d_length"] = [len(tokenizer_ger(x).input_ids) for x in train_dataset["de"]]


#length to 100, since majority of samples is shorter



train_dataset = train_dataset[train_dataset["e_length"]<100]
train_dataset = train_dataset[train_dataset["d_length"]<100]


test_dataset["e_length"] = [len(tokenizer_en(x).input_ids) for x in test_dataset["en"]]
test_dataset["d_length"] = [len(tokenizer_ger(x).input_ids) for x in test_dataset["de"]]
test_dataset = test_dataset[test_dataset["e_length"]<100]
test_dataset = test_dataset[test_dataset["d_length"]<100]

encoder_max_length=100
decoder_max_length=100

def process_data_to_model_inputs(batch):
  # tokenize the inputs and labels
  inputs = tokenizer_en(batch["en"], padding="max_length", truncation=True, max_length=encoder_max_length)
  outputs = tokenizer_ger(batch["de"], padding="max_length", truncation=True, max_length=decoder_max_length)

  batch["input_ids"] = inputs.input_ids
  batch["attention_mask"] = inputs.attention_mask
  batch["decoder_input_ids"] = outputs.input_ids
  batch["decoder_attention_mask"] = outputs.attention_mask
  batch["labels"] = outputs.input_ids.copy()

  # because BERT automatically shifts the labels, the labels correspond exactly to `decoder_input_ids`. 
  # We have to make sure that the PAD token is ignored
  batch["labels"] = [[-100 if token == tokenizer_ger.pad_token_id else token for token in labels] for labels in batch["labels"]]

  return batch

batch_size=12

train_dataset = train_dataset.map(
    process_data_to_model_inputs, 
    batched=True, 
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    remove_columns=["e_length", "d_length", "en","de"]
)

test_dataset = test_dataset.map(
    process_data_to_model_inputs, 
    batched=True, 
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    remove_columns=["e_length", "d_length", "en","de"]
)



train_dataset.set_format(
    type="torch", columns=["input_ids", "attention_mask", "decoder_input_ids", "decoder_attention_mask", "labels"],
)

test_dataset.set_format(
    type="torch", columns=["input_ids", "attention_mask", "decoder_input_ids", "decoder_attention_mask", "labels"],
)

#training




from transformers import Seq2SeqTrainingArguments, Seq2SeqTrainer
training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    predict_with_generate=True,
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
    fp16=True, 
    output_dir="/home/Documents/EN2GER",
    num_train_epochs=30,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    save_strategy = "epoch",

    save_total_limit=4,
)


trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    #compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=test_dataset,
)
trainer.train()


#generation

def generate_result(batch):
    inputs = tokenizer_en(batch["english"].to_list(), padding="max_length", truncation=True, max_length=100, return_tensors="pt")
    input_ids = inputs.input_ids
    attention_mask = inputs.attention_mask

    outputs = model.generate(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
    output_str = tokenizer_ger.batch_decode(outputs, skip_special_tokens=True)

    batch["translations"] = output_str

    return batch

df = pd.DataFrame({"english":["hello my name is Georg. nice to meet you", "what is your name?","I have been feeling under the weather lately", "How about you?"]})

generate_result(df)
```